# What is the probability that multiple spectral lines are just noise?

Tags: spectral-analysis, signal-detection, sigma-algebra

In spectroscopy spectral line emissions are related to each other, with fixed widths and heights that correlate with all lines based on fixed physical conditions. If I detect one spectral line at a 3 sigma detection level I know the likelihood that this line is not real. If I have x number of spectral lines each with a 3 sigma peak, how to a determine the likelihood that these signals are not real.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "these signals are not real."  Would that mean *all?*  *At least one?*  Something else?  And since you refer to "related to each other," that suggests you believe their appearance must not be independent.  Your question is impossible to answer without some model of this lack of independence and an estimate of the degree of correlation.  What do you have in mind?  What does the literature for this type of spectroscopy suggest?

Comment: Adding @whuber's comment: is there a specific spectrum against which you want to evaluate the observed distribution of spectral lines (e.g., white/equal energy per unit frequency, the distribution of lines some specific stellar standard, or from a specific element or group of elements in isolation, etc.)?

Comment: In addition, there are [different kinds of noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise) (notwithstanding that this link is oriented towards spectra of sound waves in audible frequencies). Do you mean a particular type?

Comment: If the spectral signal detected are from the same molecule then they are not independent and their relative frequencies are correlated. If the spectral signals are noise they could be independent noise spikes in the data. I can create an idealised model of the spectrum if it is real. The types of noise that the signal could be range from stochastic spikes to undulating patterns not related to the molecule, but the measurement technique.